# Your changes couldn't be saved show when saved Permissions DeclarationForm

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-developers-console

When i am review my app on play console then show me error "Please complete permission declaration form" but when i filled and click on saved button then show me this error "Your changes couldn't be saved".
Don't Know why this is happening i also fill all * – Required fields.

My 4 requested permission is_

```
android.permission.SEND_SMS
android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG
```

please help me for sort out this problem.

Comment: I am having the same issue, i thinks some thing is wrong with google, https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/70749182?hl=en Cause many other are having same issue!

Comment: Yes now its fixed because some thing was wrong with google.